# Bloquear fins de semana no datepicker Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

Estou usando o DatePicker do Angular Material e preciso bloquear os sábados e domingos afim de não serem selecionados. De que forma posso fazer isso ?

**Código:**

**ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {}
```

**html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma opção para manipulação deste componente é o https://momentjs.com/ verifique a documentação, tem outras opções também que futuramente podem ser muito utéis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"  [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // Prevenir Sabado e Domingo
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
```